# How may I use dotnet test specifying my project, like I used to do?

Tags: .net, dotnet-cli

How may I use `dotnet test` specifying my project, like I used to do?

I had been using this command for 5 months:

```
dotnet test ./path/to/MyTestFolder/MyTestProject.csproj
```

Yesterday it stopped work with this error:

```
Unrecognized command or argument './path/to/MyTestFolder/MyTestProject.csproj'
```

[Doc says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) this syntax is ok.

But the tool help says:

> dotnet test -h
>
> Description:   Driver de Teste do .NET
>
> Usage:   dotnet test [options] [[--] ...]]

Extra details:

- The path is fine (I checked with a dir).
- I tried to replace slash by backslash with no success.
- I tried with Command Prompt, Windows Powershell, Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022, Developer Powershell for VS 2022.
- Using Windows 11 with 2 SDK installed: 6.0.400, 7.0.102

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the sdk 7.0 and it went back to working normally.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-7.0.202-windows-x64-installer